# Could you prove that f(A)>0 whenever A>0

Tags: matrices, polynomials

A is a 3x3 matrix. A is called positive, denoted A>0, if every entry of A is positive. Let $$f(x) = x^6 - x^3 + 1$$ Could you prove that f(A)>0 whenever A>0?

Comment: what means that a matrix $A$ is positive?

Comment: (1)  Please use MathJax when formulating your post (you are a user for more than 2yrs).
(2)  Pls share your further thoughts and attempts -- right now it looks like you ask the community to solve the homework.

Answer (score 4):

This is false. Let
$$
A=\frac{1}{3}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 1 & 1 \cr 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then $f(A)=A^6-A^3+I_3=I_3$, and this matrix has not coefficients all $>0$.

Comment: As a side note I verified with CAS that with $\frac 14$ instead $f(A)$ has negative entries (though not as nice as your $A^n=A$ for all $n$).

Comment: To elaborate on this answer, when $A$ has rank one, let $A=uv^T$ for some positive vectors $u$ and $v$, and let $t=v^Tu=\operatorname{tr}(A)$. Then $f(A)=(t^5-t^3)A+I$. Therefore $f(A)$ is positive if and only if $t^5>t^3$, i.e., iff the trace of $A$ is greater than $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your counterexample and additional comments! I also learned that for 3x3 matrix A with the same entry, say u, if 0<u<1/3, then f(A)<0. My original hope was to find a polynomial of degree 6 with at least one coefficient negative such that f(A)>0 whenever A>0. Hopefully you could help me figure one such polynomial. Thank you in advance.